# How to show a text instead of 3d object in unity5 and vuforia?

Tags: image-recognition, vuforia, unity-game-engine

Hope there's a response. :(  What I want to is: Object recognition. Using Unity and Vuforia. Is it possible to make a text or a toast that will pop out or show in the camera when the objects is detected, instead of a 3d object? For example. If I detected ace of heart card. It will a show a text "ACE OF HEART"

Comment: This question is too broad - Stack Overflow is for specific questions related to programming. What you've posted is a requirement. You need to research how to use Unity and Vuforia together, and have a go. If you run into problems while you're coding, then post additional questions, preferably with code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Important tips: state your question clearly in your title-- it should not include greetings like "hello" or "please help". Also, it's not clear if your problem is with the image recognition or with displaying the feedback.. (If this is a question about what features Vuforia supports, the Vuforia developer forums might be a better place to ask.)

Comment: Sorry for that sir. I am just new here in asking in stackoverflow. I will not happen again. By the way my prob is. I want to show a text instead of 3d object. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible, ***use UI component and put it under Image target***, I think its very enough and If it is not then let me know I will put the entire content here, but belive me it is very simple try it just once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Its Possible.
You Just Have to Add Unity UI (You Just Could Use a Image with the text, in that case add an Image or you just could use a Text, so just add a Text, it's your choice) To that Object and set the Canvas in WorldSpace Mode.

And just that should do the trick.